# simple javascript JS event handler not working correctly

Tags: javascript, event-handling

Below is my code and the instructions that went with it. Currently the responseText for an incorrect answer displays on page load and I can't change it to the correct answer.

```
// Declare a string variable called question and set it equal to a True/False question of your choice. 
var question = "KD has sold his legacy at OKC for a championship ring at GS.";

// Declare a boolean variable called answer and set it equal to true or false (the answer to the question you asked above.) 
var answer = true;

// Create a function called loadQuestion() that sets the value of the questionText element equal to the question variable you declared above. 
function loadQuestion(){
document.getElementById("questionText").innerHTML = question;
}

// Create a function called checkAnswer(userAnswer) that takes one incoming parameter. 
function checkAnswer(userAnswer){
  if(userAnswer===answer){
    document.getElementById("responseText").innerHTML = "That is correct!";             
    document.getElementById("responseText").className = "correctAnswer";
  }
  else if(userAnswer!==answer){       
    document.getElementById("responseText").innerHTML = "I'm sorry, that is    
     not correct.";
    document.getElementById("responseText").className = "incorrectAnswer";
  }
}
// ---> If your answer variable matches the incoming userAnswer parameter, write a success message in the element called responseText. 
// ---> If your answer variable does NOT match the userAnswer parameter, write a failure message in the element called responseText. 

// Create TRADITIONAL DOM EVENT HANDLERS for the "onclick" events for the three buttons.
var start = document.getElementById("startButton");
var truth = document.getElementById("trueButton");
var falsify = document.getElementById("falseButton");
// The Start button should trigger the loadQuestion method
start.onclick = loadQuestion;
// The True button should trigger the checkAnswer method with a value of "true"
truth.onclick = checkAnswer("true");
// The False button should trigger the checkAnswer method with a value of "false"
falsify.onclick = checkAnswer("false");
```

Comment: If you know it should be `start.onclick = loadQuestion;`, then why did you try like `checkAnswer("true");` ?

Comment: Why didn't you write `loadQuestion()` instead of `loadQuestion` ?

Comment: do you mean i'm comparing a string w/ a boolean? i corrected that and its working now, thanks!

Comment: oh.. when you write it as a simple e.onclick = function, you don't need the parentheses, unless you have parameters, and then you have to use the anonymous function, which i was doing wrong

Comment: Yes, The _thing_ is, `onclick` or any event expects handler to be an function expression.. You were passing `undefined` as function was being `invoked` and it returned `nothing`(__undefined__)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be

```
<...>.onclick = function() {
   checkAnswer("true");
}
```

instead of

```
<...>.onclick = checkAnswer("true");
```

Comment: this worked great.. i also had to make sure i had the answer var as a string. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you are comparing as triple equality === make sure that type is the same on both sides